# How to do this in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I am trying for the first time the Tensorflow 2.0.
Is this idiomatic?

```
@tf.function
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

if __name__=="__main__":

    result=add(1.0,2.0)
    print(result)
    print(tf.keras.backend.get_value(result))
```

However, I get this warning related to the add function:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function add at 0x7ff34781a2f0> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause:
```

What does it mean?
How can I correct this?

Comment: I didn't get a warning on TF 2.0.0. Which TF version are you running?

Comment: tensorflow 2.0.0 I just installed today in Anaconda 1.9.7. I am running in Python 3.7.3. I am running in Spyder 3.3.6

Comment: What happens if you try `tf.constant(1.0)` and `tf.constant(2.0)` instead of 1.0 and 2.0?

Comment: The warning disappears!

Comment: So probably @tf.function expects tf.Tensors and tf.Variables as arguments. So if you pass int/float scalars it starts yelling.

Comment: But it's still strange that, for me it didn't give any errors/warnings.

Comment: Do you run in Jupyter or Spyder?

Comment: I'm using Jupyter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get the warning in the latest tf-nightly (2.1.0-dev20200104). But there are two pieces of advice regarding your code,

1. As @thushv89 pointed out, it is generally a good idea to pass Tensor objects 
   when calling functions decorated by `@tf.function`. In some cases, passing
   plain Python data types (like `float`s and `int`s) may cause the function
   to be "recompiled", dramatically slowing down the performance. It doesn't happen
   in this case. But it's good to be careful in general.
2. In TF2's eager execution, `tf.keras.backend.get_value(result)` is a no-op.
   You can omit that call. `result` is the Tensor value per se and it holds the
   concrete values.